# Search Controller not working in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am learning Swift and tried to create a demo app using a TableViewController with a search bar. However, I am getting a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error with console showing `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value`

The `viewDidLoad()` function is having the error

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    //Do more stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `searchController` doesn't exist. Well, it exists as an instance *variable*, but you have not assigned that variable any *value* other than `nil`. You need to *make* an actual UISearchController and *assign* it to `self.searchController`.